# Problem on laptop hp with Carrizo and Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265]

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

I write for the first time on this site because I've a problem that I can't solve. Installing ubuntu 16.04 I had some problems during boot, I was happy of my installation even if sometimes happened that the screen was flickering.
But now I must use virtual machines and I've seen that there are some errors due to the utilization of the two graphics-cards mounted on my computer.

From terminal: `inxi -Gx`

I get:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Carrizo
           bus-ID: 00:01.0
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265]
           bus-ID: 06:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: ati,amdgpu (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,radeon)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CARRIZO (DRM 3.2.0 / 4.7.0-040700-generic, LLVM 3.8.0)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

As you can see there're two graphics-cards, I'm not an expert at all, but for what I can understand the problem is with the second one..

Try to see what is the output of dmesg with:

```
dmesg > dmesg.txt
```

I noticed the following rows with errors refered to the grafics-card 06:00.0 (Topaz XT):

```
[   37.937714] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[   38.296781] [drm:gfx_v8_0_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: cp failed to lock ring 0 (-2).
[   38.296846] [drm:amdgpu_resume [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume 4 failed -2
[   38.296892] [drm:amdgpu_resume_kms [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu_resume failed (-2).
[   38.297136] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   38.297219] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   38.297283] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   38.308122] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   38.308135] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   38.308147] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   38.614838] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   38.614901] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   38.614932] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.609267] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.609323] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.609351] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.609368] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.609392] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.609417] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.609427] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.609451] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.609475] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.610291] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.610341] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.610365] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.610430] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.610454] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.610478] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.610529] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.610554] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.610577] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.610650] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.610675] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.610699] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.610911] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.610938] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.610964] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.611028] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.611060] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.611086] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.614858] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.614925] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.614959] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.615819] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.615872] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.615897] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.615970] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.615995] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.616019] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.616066] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.616091] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.616115] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.616172] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.616197] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.616221] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.616352] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.616384] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.616409] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.617207] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.617248] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.617273] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   39.619123] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   39.619183] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   39.619212] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   40.263909] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   40.263967] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   40.263999] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   40.264131] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   40.264156] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   40.264182] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
[   40.264209] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   40.264233] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   40.264258] [drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
```

I searched on Google and I've read that with kernel 4.5 the problem will be partially solved, so I tried to install it but I've seen that the problem remained. I tried kernel 4.7, but the problem remain but the errors given by dmesg are different:

```
[    5.729661] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000060, cpu addr 0xffff880405f13060
[    5.729782] [drm:amdgpu_ring_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to register debugfs file for rings !
[    5.730075] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000074, cpu addr 0xffff880405f13074
[    5.730111] [drm:amdgpu_ring_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to register debugfs file for rings !
[    5.730224] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: fence driver on ring 6 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000088, cpu addr 0xffff880405f13088
[    5.730259] [drm:amdgpu_ring_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to register debugfs file for rings !
[    5.730721] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: fence driver on ring 7 use gpu addr 0x000000008000009c, cpu addr 0xffff880405f1309c
[    5.730838] [drm:amdgpu_ring_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to register debugfs file for rings !
[    5.731453] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: fence driver on ring 8 use gpu addr 0x00000000800000b0, cpu addr 0xffff880405f130b0
[    5.731572] [drm:amdgpu_ring_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to register debugfs file for rings !
[    5.732351] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: fence driver on ring 9 use gpu addr 0x00000000800000c4, cpu addr 0xffff880405f130c4
[    5.732469] [drm:amdgpu_ring_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to register debugfs file for rings !
[    5.733046] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: fence driver on ring 10 use gpu addr 0x00000000800000d8, cpu addr 0xffff880405f130d8
[    5.733133] [drm:amdgpu_ring_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to register debugfs file for rings !
[    6.094603] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 12 usecs
[    6.094847] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 16 usecs
[    6.094887] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 13 usecs
[    6.094897] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    6.094906] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    6.094914] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    6.094923] [drm] ring test on 6 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    6.094932] [drm] ring test on 7 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    6.094940] [drm] ring test on 8 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    6.094983] [drm] ring test on 9 succeeded in 5 usecs
[    6.094991] [drm] ring test on 10 succeeded in 4 usecs
[    6.095354] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.095716] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.095965] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.096026] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.096069] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.096201] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.096243] [drm] ib test on ring 6 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.096279] [drm] ib test on ring 7 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.096317] [drm] ib test on ring 8 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.096369] [drm] ib test on ring 9 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.096408] [drm] ib test on ring 10 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    6.096835] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.2.0 20150101 for 0000:06:00.0 on minor 1
```

I hope somebody can help me ^^_

Furthermore ... I've not dual-boot just linux installed, but I've two desktop-environments KDE and PLASMA. I don't know if this can be important for the solution.

PS. Sorry for my english, I'm Italian!